# Alternate definiton of limit from epsilon delta definition

Tags: real-analysis

From the epsilon delta definition of a limit, $\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)=L$ if and only if $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$ when $0<|x-x_0|<\delta$ I drew a few diagrams and noticed, that for an increasing function, this definition means that if the limit exists,

$f(x_0-\delta)>L-\epsilon$ and

$f(x_0+\delta)<L+\epsilon$

After some rearranging, I got

$-L>-f(x_0-\delta)-\epsilon$ and

$L>f(x_0+\delta)-\epsilon$

Adding these two inequalities together, I got

$f(x_0+\delta)-f(x_0-\delta)-2\epsilon<0$

My question is, for an increasing function, if we prove that there is a delta such that the above condition is satisfied for any $\epsilon$ we choose, is this a sufficient condition for the limit to exist?

Comment: Not bad. This is a variant of what is called the "Cauchy condition", which proves convergence without having to know what the limit is ahead of time. The Cauchy condition is very important in analysis. It works for real and complex numbers, but if $f$ were defined into the rational numbers instead of the reals, it would fail. The reason is, the function may converge to a limit, but the limit need not be rational. The rational numbers are full of holes. The real numbers are what you get when you fill those holes in. The Cauchy condition is why filling those holes is important.